# how to add multiple foreign colums in one fact table

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse

here is my sql code that contains dimension tables as well as fact table ... the problem that i'm facing is that i want to add multiple foreign keys of dimensios in my fact table .... kindly help me where i'm doing wrong either in syntax or code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bouquet_DT](
[Bouquet_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[Flowers] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Size] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Cost_per_Unit] [numeric](10, 2) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City_DT](
[City_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[City_Name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer_DT](
[Customer_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[Customer_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Customer_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Customer_City] [char](10) NULL,
[CNIC] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Gender] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Age] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
[Customer_PhoneNo] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MembershipCard_DT](
[Card_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[Discount%] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[Duration_in_Years] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Price] [numeric](10, 2) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Occasion_DT](
[Occasion_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[Occasion_Name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales_FT](

[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Unit_Quantity] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[SalePrice_Per_Unit] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[MembershiP_TyPe] [char](10) NULL,
[Discount] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[Delivery_CharGes] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[Store_ID] [char] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Store_DT]([Store_ID])
[Customer_ID] [char] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer_DT] 
([Customer_ID])
[Bouquet_ID] [char] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Bouquet_DT]([Bouquet_ID])
[Occasion_ID] [char] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[OccasionDT] 
([Occasion_ID])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Store_DT](
[Store_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL primary key,
[Store_Manager] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Store_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Store_Area] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Store_City] [char](10) NULL
)
```

Comment: What `fact` table? Can't see it.

Comment: sale_FT this is fact table and dimension table are named as xyz_DT

Comment: I assume it's SALES_FT.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have referenced dbo.OccasionDT, i.e. missing underscore.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
Incorrect syntax near 'Customer_ID'.

Comment: this is the error i'm facing

Comment: it is running Store_ID foreign key but not the remaing three of them

Comment: Looks like you need some commas.

Comment: Yeah, several commas missing there.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any restrictions on having multiple foreign keys. You can add as many as you want.

In SQL Server I commonly use a different syntax. For example for the column `Store_ID`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales_FT](
  ...
  [Store_ID] [char],
  constraint fk1 foreign key (Store_ID)
    references Store_DT (Store_ID),
  ...
);
```

This syntax always works for me.

Comment: You must use different names for each constraint. Whatever names you prefer, but they must be different.

Comment: still by using fk1,fk2,fk3,fk4 different names i'm getting this error

Comment: Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 48
Foreign key 'fk1' references invalid table 'dbo.Store_DT'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: You need to create a table before it can be referenced.

Comment: Msg 1753, Level 16, State 0, Line 48
Column 'dbo.Store_DT.Store_ID' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'Sales_FT.Store_ID' in foreign key 'fk1'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.

Comment: Yep, those two columns are different. The FK is `char`, the PK is `char(10)`. Change one of them to match the other one.